# Getting a TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when I run the code below, some please explain what I may be doing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
theBoard = {}
theBoard.setdefault({1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3',
                     4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6',
                     7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9'})
```

Comment: The first argument of `dict.setdefault()` is supposed to be the key, and keys should be hashable objects. And that's when you've passed a dictionary as the key.

Comment: maybe you should explain what your goal is.

Answer (score 1):

```
theBoard = {}
theBoard.update({1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3',
                     4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6',
                     7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9'})
```